# Swift Multiples App running error

Tags: swift2

I have running an issue with the Multiples App. I was just trying out and see if I can get the function right. However, this app can only run once, the addition itself is correct but when the game starts over, it will throw an error. Please help ~~

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
        @IBOutlet weak var AddBtn: UIButton!
        @IBOutlet weak var TextInput: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var ResultLabel: UILabel!
        var CurrentNum = 0
        var SecondNum = 0
        let MaxNum = 30

        func currentNumUpdate(sum: Int, Mul: Int, nSum: Int){
            ResultLabel.text = "\(sum) + \(Mul) = \(nSum)"
            }

          @IBAction func AddtionBtn(sender: UIButton) {
            let TotalSum = CurrentNum + SecondNum
            currentNumUpdate(CurrentNum, Mul: SecondNum, nSum: TotalSum)
            CurrentNum += SecondNum
        if (TextInput != nil && TextInput != ""){
            SecondNum = Int(TextInput.text!)!
            }

        if GameOver(){
        GameStartOver()

        }
    }
        func GameOver() -> Bool{

            if (CurrentNum > MaxNum){
            return true

            }else {
               return false
            }

    }
        func GameStartOver(){
            ResultLabel.hidden = false
            TextInput.text = ""
            AddBtn.hidden = false
            ResultLabel.text = "Again"

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post the full error log, and beware your code formatting is weird in your question

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time post question here, not sure how to indent the code here... the error is " fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value "

Comment: The line  SecondNum = Int(TextInput.text!)! is probably causing an issue. Try to comment some lines to find which line causes the issue

Comment: Yes, that line SecondNum = Int(TextInput.text!)! is the issue, but I am not sure why, I will have to pass the user input value to the Text field in order to do the calculation.. is the syntax wrong?

Comment: Just double check all Outlet connections in your storyboard file. If you renamed one of UI elements after you added connection this will cause an error

Comment: Thank you, I have checked it and resolved the issue :)